# FFMPEG cut for time range

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line-arguments

I am using the below command for having 15sec - 45 sec range of music but sample.m4a file is starting from 15 sec to 60 sec. Am I using the wrong syntax or why it is so?

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:45 -i song.m4a -acodec copy sample.m4a
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `-t` flag sets duration.
So in case you want 15sec-45sec range you must set `-t 00:00:30` (i.e. 45-15=30) and use -t parameter after filename for make it output parameter.

Full command will look like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15 -i song.m4a -t 00:00:30 -acodec copy sample.m4a
```

And alternatively

```
ffmpeg -ss 15 -i song.m4a -t 30 -acodec copy sample.m4a
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `-to` instead of `-t`.

1. `-t` specifies the duration
2. `-to` specifies the end time

---

If you'd like to grab 30 seconds starting from 00:00:15, you can either:

1) Specify the start time and duration.

```
-ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:30
```

2) Alternatively, specify the start time and end time.

```
-ss 00:00:15 -to 00:00:45
```

Both will grab the same 30 seconds of video.

Comment: Please make the relation between `-to`, `-t:` and `-t` more clear.

Comment: @peterh I was confused by the `-t:` momentarily, but I think the colon in the original answer was just punctuation, so it's just `-to` and `-t`.